# Find the number of balls in a jar

Tags: statistics

The question is this: 
A jar contains only red and green balls. Ten red balls are added and then the green balls now constitute 20 percent of the total. In addition, ten green balls are added, making the percentage of green balls equal to 40 percent of the total. How many balls were originally in the jar?

I don't know to solve this. Please help me.

Comment: I dont think this is a statistics question.

Comment: I don't know what should be the tag.

Answer (score 2):

HINT:

Solve the following system of two equations in two variables:

- $\color\green{y}=\frac{20}{100}\cdot(\color\red{x}+10+\color\green{y})$
- $10+\color\green{y}=\frac{40}{100}\cdot(\color\red{x}+10+\color\green{y}+10)$

Comment: Can you answer it?

Comment: @StephenMark: Is this homework?

Comment: @StephenMark You may be missing the point of this site. The point is not to solve every question for you. It is to help you solve your questions, and in the process learn something. barakmanos gave you a very good hint about how to solve your problem. He reduced it to a problem of solving a system of two equations with two variables, which you should be able to solve. If you are not, then you need to first study up on these kinds of problems before you tackle more difficult ones.

Comment: I got the answer thanks